# How to replace this strange quote-looking symbol: “, with a proper double quote: "

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea that is used as the body of an email sent out by a Java class.
A user has reported that after copying text from Apple's Keynote, and sending an email, characters that are supposed to be double quotes, show as '?'.

On further inspection it seems the user has used this symbol: “  , rather than the typical ' " ' .

I have been trying to replace this symbol in javascript (without success) by using:

```
   str.replace("“", '"')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted does work:

```
> "“".replace("“", '"')
"""
```

However, this won't solve the issue, as you'll get similar results for other unicode characters.

This is an issue that will need to be fixed on the back-end, as that's most likely where the Unicode is being handled incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, David.  I accidentally submitted my question partially-completed, but you have still answered what I was looking for.

Comment: Does anyone know of a website/resource where you could paste a symbol and be told what the unicode character code is?

Comment: Don't know about website, but you can use `.charCodeAt`: `"“".charCodeAt(0)`.